# Proof that $n/(n^2+1)$ tends to 0 as $n$ tends to infinity

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm trying to use Leibniz theorem to show that a series converges and to complete the proof I need to show that $$\frac{n}{n^2+1}$$ goes to $0$ as $n$ tends to infinity.

Comment: What do you mean by the "Leibniz theorem"?  He has several, and none of the ones that I'm thinking of apply to this problem.

Comment: Im thinking the OP means Leibniz's Alternating Series Test..

Answer (score 13):

all you need is to notice that

$n^2 + 1 \gt n^2 $

taking reciprocals reverses the inequality, i.e. $\frac1{n^2 +1} \lt \frac1{n^2}$

as $n$ is positive, multiplying by it doesn't change the inequality, so 
$\frac{n}{n^2 +1} \lt \frac{n}{n^2}$

the right-hand term simplifies to $\frac1{n}$ which obviously tends to zero as $n \rightarrow \infty$

since the left-hand term is smaller, this must also tend to zero with $n \rightarrow \infty$

Comment: Thank you for your answer to my question about groups. Because it was marked as duplicate and downvoted I deleted it. But I want to thank you for your help. Therefore I am upvoting this answer of yours (which is also good) instead of the other.

Comment: @astudent very thoughtful of you. all the best with your studies ;-)

Comment: If you don't mind, really only if you don't mind, you could repost that other answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1520525/g-finite-abelian-a-b-in-g-what-can-we-say-about-langle-a-b-rangle). I would upvote and accept it. The fact that you mentioned that it's one of the isomorphism theorems was absolutely key to helping me understand.

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{n^2+1}$$

Divide through by the highest power of $n$.

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\frac{n}{n^2}}{\frac{n^2}{n^2} + \frac{1}{n^2}}$$

$\frac{n}{n^2}$ and $\frac{1}{n^2}$ $\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{0}{1+0} = \frac{0}{1} = 0$$

Answer (score 1):

Note, that in general, $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac {p(n)}{q(n)} 0, $$ if $ \text {deg}(p) < \text{deg}(q) $. A rigorous proof of this could be done as above or by l'Hoptial's Rule $d$ times, where $d=\text{deg}(p)$.