# $G$ finite Abelian, $a,b\in G$ what can we say about $|\langle a,b\rangle|$?

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

I tried to answer the following question:

Let $G$ be a finite Abelian group and $a,b \in G$. Let

$$ \langle a,b \rangle = \{a^i b^j \mid i,j \in \mathbb Z \}$$

What can we say about $|\langle a,b \rangle|$ in terms of $|a|,|b|$?

My answer:

$|\langle a,b \rangle| = lcm(|a|,|b|)$.

But it's not so clear to me how to prove this claim. For example, this subgroup of $G$ is not cyclic. If it was it would be obvious. But maybe my claim about the order is wrong.

> Is my claim wrong? If not, how to prove it rigorously?

Comment: So you are claiming that, if $|a|=|b|$, then $|\langle a,b\rangle|=|a|$? I have some doubts about that. What if $G$ is the non-cyclic group of order $4$?

Comment: Yes that is correct. To prove it first show that $<a,b>$ raised to the order you have obtained is in fact identity. Then show that no smaller power is identity.

Comment: I think you can say that $|\langle a,b\rangle|\le|a||b|.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comment your claim is wrong. In general you have :

$$max(|a|,|b|)\leq |\langle a,b\rangle|\leq |a||b| $$

The left inequality being proven by considering that $\langle a\rangle$ and $\langle b\rangle\subseteq \langle a,b\rangle$. The equality is obtained if and only if $a\in \langle b\rangle$ or $b\in \langle a\rangle$.

The right inequality is obtained by considering the obvious surjective morphism of groups :

$$\langle a\rangle\times\langle b\rangle\rightarrow  \langle a,b\rangle$$

$$(a^k,b^l)\mapsto a^kb^l $$

One can see that we get equality if and only if $\langle a\rangle \cap\langle b\rangle=\{1_G\}$ so exactly when the intersection is trivial (in which the surjective morphism is also injective and leads to an isomorphis of groups).

Finally one can actually relate $m:=lcm(|a|,|b|)$ to the group $\langle a,b\rangle$. You can show (it is an interesting exercise) that $m$ is the biggest order of an element of the group $\langle a,b\rangle$. In other words, $m$ is the exponent of $\langle a,b\rangle$.

One last thing (following ZoeH's comment), by the first inequality argument $|a|$ and $|b|$ divide $|\langle a,b\rangle|$ so that $lcm(|a|,|b|)$ divides $|\langle a,b\rangle|$ and $|\langle a,b\rangle|$ divides $|a||b|$ since the application in the second inequality argument is a group morphism.

Comment: You observe that $\langle a,b\rangle$ has an element of order $\operatorname{lcm}(|a|,|b|)$, but this means that $\operatorname{lcm}(|a|,|b|)$ is a divisor of $|\langle a,b\rangle|$, which gives a better (or at least no worse) lower bound for $|\langle a,b\rangle|$. Your argument  for the upper bound also shows that $|\langle a,b\rangle|$ divides $|a||b|$.

Comment: @ZoeH, you are right, the thing being that with the inequalities I wrote, one can explicitely find the equality cases... I added your remark.

Comment: Thank you this is a nice answer. There is one small typo: you wrote prooved instead of proved. Would you delete one of the os? (Oh, and there is also sees instead of see.)

Comment: @astudent, thank you for the grammar correction, I edited it.

Answer (score 2):

We can say $|\langle a,b\rangle|$ is a divisor of $|a|.|b|$ and divisible by $|a|$ and $|b|$.

Consider the group $\mathbb{Z}_4\times \mathbb{Z}_2.$ Consider $a=(1,0)$ and $b=(1,1)$. Then $|\langle a,b\rangle|=|G|=8$ and is not the lcm of the orders of $a$ and $b$ (which are $4$ for both).

We can say this: since $G$ is abelian, $\langle a,b\rangle=\langle a\rangle . \langle b\rangle$, and there is well known formula for order of such product:
$$|\langle a,b\rangle| = |\langle a\rangle.\langle b\rangle|=\frac{|\langle a\rangle|.|\langle b\rangle|}{|\langle a\rangle \cap  \langle b\rangle|}$$